# How do I cd and then ls in my cshrc

Tags: linux, ls, cd-command, csh

I want to be able to cd into a path and have it `ls` automatically.
I have tried doing a function such as

```
cs() { cd "@a" ; ls}
```

but this results in an error saying "badly placed ()" so I do not think I can do functions. I have also tried

```
alias cs ' cd !:1 ; ls '
```

I can source my .cshrc with this but when I call it, it doesn't do anything and I am still in the same folder.

Comment: See also `alias cwdcmd ls` (assuming your csh is actually tcsh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very very close. 
Unix loves backslashes; Unix eats backslashes for breakfast. 
You need

```
alias cs 'cd \!:1; ls'
```

If you look at the documentation for csh (and its descendants),
you'll see that `!` refers to the history mechanism,
which lets you refer to previous command(s). 
The simplest example is `!!`,
which recalls and repeats the most recent command. 
`!:1` means word #1 from the referenced command
(where the command itself is word #0;
so, for example, in `grep needle *.txt`, 
`!:0` is `grep` and `!:1` is `needle`).

Bash and other descendants of the Bourne shell have a feature
that is *very* similar.

C shell aliases are a little weird. 
When you run an alias, the command *that you typed*
(e.g., `cs vacation_photographs`) is treated as the "previous command". 
So, when the alias runs, `!:1` is replaced with `vacation_photographs`.

The catch is that this happens *when the alias **runs**.* 
But history expansion happens when the alias is ***defined***, too.
So, for example, if your `.cshrc` says

```
set prompt = '% '
alias cs 'cd !:1; ls'
```

then `!:1` is evaluated ***as `prompt`***,
and the alias is defined as `cd prompt; ls`. 
To be able to refer to the command that you typed
(`vacation_photographs`),
you need to define the alias to be `cd !:1; ls`,
and so you need to use the backslash
to defer the interpretation of the `!:1`,
so it will be evaluated when the alias is run
instead of when it is defined.

If you've been doing

```
alias cs 'cd !:1; ls'
```

and it doesn't do *anything* (not even give you an error message),
I cannot explain that.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Just wondering, why is it that the \ was required?

Comment: AFAIK, bash and zsh are the only Bourne-like shells that have implemented csh-like history expansion.

Comment: Muscle memory always make me type cd instead of cs... is using `alias cd 'cd \!:1; ls'` allowed? Planning to place this at ~/.cshrc.user with `if ($?USER == 0 || $?prompt == 0) exit` at the very top line of the file.

Comment: @CarlaH: [One version of csh(1) that I found](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/csh.1.html) says “Looping (in the context of alias substitution) is prevented if the first word of the new text is the same as the old by flagging it to prevent further aliasing.”  And, indeed, ``alias cd 'cd \!:1; ls'`` seems to work.  I encourage you to try things like this yourself to ***see*** whether they work before you ask a question.